# To get the max entity_id in customer_address_entity table in magento

Tags: magento

I am new in magento , if anyone know how to get the max entity_id in customer_address_entity table please reply soon

Answer (score 0):

By using mysql

```
select entity_id from customer_address_entity order by entity_id desc
```

By using Magento Collection

```
echo "<pre>";
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
print_r($collection->getData());
```